# AWS lambda memory consumption request pipe

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, request, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function, very simple:

```
'use strict';

var request = require('request');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new aws.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var stream = require('fs').createWriteStream('/tmp/tmpFile');

    request
        .get(event.url)
        .pipe(stream);

};
```

But, when I try to download a 50MB file, my function runs out of memory (used: 139, max: 128). I really don't understand because the file is kind of small.

Do you have an idea where it could come from?